# Discord.py message sender problem with commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a pretty basic script that I want to use to call a command every hour for a discord bot.
The problem is, discord does not recognize the command I send as a command, only as a message.
For example "/cooldown" should show me my cooldown on commands, but when the app sends "/cooldown" nothing happens, it only shows the message "/cooldown".

This is the code:

```
import discord
import time
import requests
import json
import datetime

token = "My User Token"

channel_id = "My channel id"

message_content = "/cooldown"

# Function to send a message to the specified channel
def send_message(token, channel_id, content):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": token
    }
    data = {
        "content": message_content
    }
    url = f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{channel_id}/messages"

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Message sent successfully.")
    else:
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Failed to send message.")

# Main loop to send messages every hour
while True:
    send_message(token, channel_id, message_content)
    time.sleep(5)
```

It sends the message, but it just doesn't send it as a command.

I am expecting this:

[image: Expected]

But I am getting this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi! Have you ever worked with discord.py before? If not I recommend watching some tutorials on it. What you expect is called an embed and there is a really different way to create one. I don't even see a bot in your code. It would be really long to explain everything from zero. But if you are interested I can help you get started with discord.py. Message me on discord (@rexy.py) because this site is not for a complete tutorial but for solving some problems. I'll help you through discord :D